# How to re-open a closed file descriptor

Tags: c, pipe

I have a scenario where i created pipe for communication between two child and parent. Parent writes (using write function)data to the pipe and closes the respective file descriptor. The problem is when i want to write data again to the pipe, the write function is returning error code -1. I think its because writing end has been closed in previous iteration. Then how to open the corresponding file descriptor after it has been closed once.

I tried using open() function which requires path to some file as arguement. But i am not using any files in my application. I have simple file descriptors (int arr[2]).

Is it possible to achieve above scenario with pipes????

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once a pipe is closed, it's closed.  You can't bring it back.

If you want to write more to it, don't close it in the first place - it's as simple as that.

Comment: if we dont close the file descriptor, it will not send EOF to the respective stream. So in the child process it will wait continuously for input. But, i want to write limited number of times to the stream and read concurrently at the other end of pipe

Comment: @chaitu: It is true that if you do not close the writing end, the reading end will not show end-of-file.  This means that you need to use something other than end-of-file to denote the end of your message, if you want to send more messages to the child (typically, you would use a fixed-length message so the child knows how long it is).

Comment: @chaitu can you post your solution or workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

Thing to know about anything related to files (pipes are also some sort of files) under unix: file name is used only on opening file. Later until file is open, it is available forever until closed and name is never used again. When someone deletes file in another window while it is open, just name is gone, not file. This means:

1. File is still on disk
2. It has no name
3. It is still open
4. When it is closed, kernel removes it forever

Knowing this maybe helps to understand, why this would be nearly impossible to "reopen" file, pipe or anything similar again. File name and descriptor have different lifetimes.

The only exceptions are stdout and stderr whose descriptor are always known as 1 and 2.